# Ubuntu 12.04 taking too much time to boot

Tags: grub2, kernel

Ubuntu 12.04 is taking much time for booting, Here is the system kernel message while booting .It is showing that some anacron was killed ,why ? and how to fix the problem ?

```
[    2.241047] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0
[    2.241501] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.241895] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    3.240670] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multiple Card  Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[    3.241791] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    3.243083] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   12.568641] Adding 4037904k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4037904k 
[   12.615014] udevd[462]: starting version 175
[   12.651334] mei: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   12.655283] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
...................
[   14.118369] init: alsa-restore main process (982) terminated with status 19
[   14.252595] init: anacron main process (1033) killed by TERM signal
[   14.285763] HDMI status: Codec=3 Pin=5 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[   14.285841] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[   14.285925] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[   14.285991] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[   14.615073] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1222) terminated with status 1
[   16.447287] wlan0: authenticate with c0:8a:de:7c:60:e8 (try 1)
[   16.448858] wlan0: authenticated
[   16.453405] wlan0: associate with c0:8a:de:7c:60:e8 (try 1)
[   16.456392] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c0:8a:de:7c:60:e8 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[   16.456398] wlan0: associated
[   16.457014] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[   16.457017] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[   16.457019] ieee80211 phy0: changing basic rates failed: -22
[   16.457021] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 0 (implement)
[   16.457226] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   16.654196] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 1 (implement)
[   17.823565] ieee80211 phy0: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 180/256 dur 1946/1504
[   18.220865] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[   26.881422] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[   68.228293] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[   73.240133] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[   76.574490] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  102.180006] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  103.100984] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  124.171624] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like conflict between two network managers. In this case LAN and Wireless.
I can suggest you to disable Wireless from loading at boot.
Or if it possible move Wireless down by startup priority (btw i.e. ***Upstart***).